# Automatic number issued by the system with array

Tags: c++

I wrote:

```
 string a[100] = { "B", "F", "R", "P", "D", "\0" };
class BD{
//data member
static int id;
//.......
};


 void setid(int d){ id = d;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        id = i + 1;
        user[id];
    }
cout << " ID : " << id << endl;
    }



 int BD::id = 0;
```

in this code, has an array include name of user and for each user a different ID number but in run (output) always will be **5** !
I know it's a logical error.
 when enter : `B`

```
ID : 5
```

but I want to print :

```
 if user enter name  `B`


ID : 1
```

if user enter name `F`

```
ID : 2
```

Comment: I don't see any output. Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: move your `cout` statement _inside_ your `for` loop.

Comment: I don't want to print all id of user, only name entered by user

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting id in the loop

```
    id = i + 1;
```

Thus as the last i used in the body of the loop is equal to 4 then you always get that id = 5

EDIT:
If you want to find a string in an array of strings and return its index + 1 then the function can look like

```
int getId( const std::string &s )
{ 
    string a[100] = { "B", "F", "R", "P", "D", "\0" };

    int id = 0;

    while ( a[id] != "\0" && a[id] != s ) ++id;

    return a[id] == "\0" ? 0 : id + 1;
}
```

However it seems you do not understand the difference between objects of type std::string and character arrays and string literals. So you need something different than the function I showed.

Comment: @Bsh I do not understand what you are trying to get. Could you explain what id you are expecting?